# What is the default font of tkinter label?

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, label

What is the default font of `tkinter` `Label`? If I want to change the label font size, `tkinter` forces me to define a font type as well (as a tuple, e.g. `('Arial', 20)`), but I do **not** want to change the font that is being used. Is it Arial? Is it Courier?

Comment: It's **not**. `('Courier', 20)` results in a completely different font with serifs. Try it on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, its ```TkDefaultFont```

Comment: The answer may be OS specific.

Comment: yes @martineau, I am on windows 10 and The font I get is ```Segoe UI```

Comment: So the answer is—at least partially—that it can only to be determined dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 10):

It will be set as the `TkDefaultFont` value. You can check this value by starting a `Tk()` instance and then checking for the default font.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import font

root = tkinter.Tk()  # Start Tk instance
your_font = font.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")  # Get default font value into Font object
your_font.actual()
```

Comment: FWIW, the `nametofont()` and `actual()` methods are mentioned in the `tkinter.font` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.font.html).

Answer (score 4):

```
    from tkinter import *

    from tkinter import font

    root=Tk()

    print(font.nametofont('TkTextFont').actual())

    root.mainloop()
```

Output :

```
{'family': 'Segoe UI', 'size': 9, 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'underline': 0, 'overstrike': 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, try this program. The default I get is `Segoe UI`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
root=Tk()
l1=Label(root,text="Hello")
l1.pack()
Button(root,text='get label font',command=lambda: print(font.nametofont(l1['font']).configure()["family"])).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's bad practise to use a list inside a `lambda` in order to call multiple functions.

Comment: @TheLizzard: A list is not being used inside a `lambda` here. Regardless, you're also incorrect about it being a bad practice to use one to make multiple calls in one.

Comment: @martineau The list was edited out. Also there is no way to have multiple commands in 1 line with the `lambda` without going over the 80 character per line guideline (PEP8).