# Unicode "floppy disk" character isn't displayed in tkinter window on Pop!_OS

Tags: python, tkinter, unicode

I am trying to integrate a Unicode character into the text of a tkinter widget like a button. This seems to work for some characters like the Greek capital letter Omega (Ω) but not for others like the floppy disk symbol ().

When I run the following script, only the Omega appears on the Button and in place of the floppy disk symbol there is an empty space:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(text=u"\U000003A9" + u"\U0001F4BE")
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

[image: Window created by code]

If I print both symbols using

```py
print(u"\U000003A9" + u"\U0001F4BE")
```

I get the correct result of `Ω`.

What is the problem here?

I am using python 3.9.7 on Pop!_OS 21.10.

Comment: It works for me, on Debian Linux.

Comment: And it works for me on Windows 10.

Comment: It might be worth checking which font is being used by your version of Tk. Maybe it just doesn't have that symbol.

Comment: Using `button.cget('font')` I get `TkDefaultFont`.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68375504/407651.

Comment: This gets me the result `DejaVu Sans`. The floppy disk character exists in this font.

Comment: How did you get this u"\U000003A9" + u"\U0001F4BE"?

Comment: What do you mean?